# What are the elements of the quadratic ring $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{15}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Hi MathStackExchange,

I am having trouble understanding this quadratic ring: $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$$ whose elements can be written as $$ \{a+b\sqrt{15} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
If anyone understands what these elements actually look like,and could provide a few examples, that would be very helpful.
Wikipedia describes the set as :
"The ring Z[ω] consists of all roots of all equations $x^2 + Bx + C = 0$whose discriminant $B^2 − 4C$ is the product of D by the square of an integer. In particular √D belongs to Z[ω], being a root of the equation $x^2 − D = 0$, which has 4D as its discriminant." [link to page - see Quadratic Rings section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer)

...which doesn't seem to match the other expression I have for the elements.

For example, is something like(just a random example) $999999 + (-2)\sqrt{15}$ in this ring? It seems like it could be from the way the elements can be represented?

#### My Answer (see approved answer for more detail):

My example $999999 + (-2)\sqrt{15}$ is indeed an element of the quadratic ring. In general, the motivation for mentioning rings of this type in Algebra textbooks/lectures is that they have so many interesting properties. For example, notice that $\mathbb[Z\sqrt{15}]$ is not a Unique Factorization Domain. You can find two different factorizations of irreducible elements for some elements in the ring.

Quadratic integer rings are explicitly defined like [this](http://oeis.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer_rings), which makes it clear to see that elements of this ring in particular are indeed of the form $ \{a+b\sqrt{15} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: Please give a link for the Wikipedia quote.

Comment: Done. Also I've answered my own question and will be posting an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *definition* of ${\mathbb Z}[\omega]$ is
$$\{a + b \omega \mid a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$$
or, more generally for $\omega$ that are not the root of a *quadratic* equation
$$\{\sum_{j=0}^{n} c_j \omega^j \mid n \in {\mathbb N}, c_0, \dots, c_n \in {\mathbb Z}\}.$$

What you quote from Wikipedia is a property that quadratic rings happen to have - and it is not hard to show, but is not immediately obvious -; the actual definition is in the line right before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a subring of $\Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{C}$). For any complex number $t$ then $\Bbb{Z}[t]$ is a subring of $\Bbb{C}$, and when $t$ is the root of a monic integer polynomial of degree $n$ then $\Bbb{Z}[t] = \{ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} c_j t^j, c_j\in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure that this definition clarified it. Do you mind providing explicit examples? When you say "yes" do you mean my example of 999999+(−2)sqrt(15) is indeed in the ring?

Comment: sure, take $a=999999,b=-2$. For every integer polynomial $f(x)$ then $f(\sqrt{15})$ is in the ring, that's the definition of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$, the theorem is that we need only polynomials of degree $\le 1$.